# Python with NLTK shows error at sent_tokenize and word_tokenize

Tags: python, nltk

I am using Google Colab to work on a script that I learn through video. Unfortunately, I get an error though following the video instructions.

```
sentences_tokens=nltk.sent_tokenize(allParagraphContent_cleanedData)
words_tokens=nltk.word_tokenize(allParagraphContent_cleanedData)
```

causes a problem. Both lines. I have tried each of it standing alone, in Python 3 (which I use mainly).
Here are the imported libraries:

```
from urllib import request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import re
import nltk
import heapq
```

The error I get is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

LookupError                               Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-13-2467ae276de5> in <module>()
     26 allParagraphContent_cleanedData=re.sub(r'\s+','',allParagraphContent_cleanedData)
     27 
---> 28 sentences_tokens=nltk.sent_tokenize(allParagraphContent_cleanedData)
     29 words_tokens=nltk.word_tokenize(allParagraphContent_cleanedData)
     30
```

Frankly spoken, I don't understand the error.

What's the problem that I don't see?

--
Here's the whole code

```
from urllib import request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import re
import nltk
import heapq



url="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_learning"
allParagraphContent = ""
htmlDoc=request.urlopen(url)
soupObject=bs(htmlDoc,'html.parser')



for paragraphContent in paragraphContents:
    allParagraphContent += paragraphContent.text


allParagraphContent_cleanerData=re.sub(r'\[0-9]*\]','',allParagraphContent)
allParagraphContent_cleanedData=re.sub(r'\s+','',allParagraphContent_cleanerData)



allParagraphContent_cleanedData=re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z]','',allParagraphContent_cleanedData)
allParagraphContent_cleanedData=re.sub(r'\s+','',allParagraphContent_cleanedData)

sentences_tokens=nltk.sent_tokenize(allParagraphContent_cleanedData)
words_tokens=nltk.word_tokenize(allParagraphContent_cleanedData)
```

The solution:
adding `nltk.download("popular")` after `import nltk`

Comment: What happens if you use `nltk.download()` right after importing the library?

Comment: Hold on, I inserted the line, started the script. Loading. May take some time.

Comment: Got the solution. You gave me the right direction. I needed: *nltk.download("popular")*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error usually appears when there's a module missing. This can be solved by using the `download()` method and specifying the module. Furthermore, you can pass `'all'` and just download everything. The code would be:

```
nltk.download('all')
```